# GraphQL Reduct Response

Tags: graphql

I have a response from GraphQL which is similar to:

```
"data": {
  "x": {
    "y":{
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": 123
        },
        {
          "id": 123
        },

        {
          "id": 456
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reduce this so that no duplicate IDs come, using the graphQL query.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL doesn't include any way to filter or manipulate the response data that comes back from the server.  If you have a query like

```
x { y { nodes { id } } }
```

you will always get back what the server sends you.  It's possible the schema and the server will define some sort of extended filtering query argument or deduplication, but this is not a defined part of GraphQL proper.